# My question with 1000+ view is closed

Tags: support

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628279/checking-for-null-or-empty-string-in-mysql-table-field

I think the sheer popularity of it should warrent it to be opened. Clearly people are finding it useful in answering this specific question.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it was a duplicate anyway.

Comment: 1000 views is not popular at all. Also, being popular has absolutely nothing to do with how good the question is.

Answer (score 22):

1000 views is no popular, not for a 6 months old question that shows 0 research effort and is phrased is such a way that it is not likely to be helpful to others.

Note that is was closed the very next day after it was asked. Thanks to you now pointing attention to it, it will probably get deleted by the community soon too.

Comment: Clear question, clear answer. I disagree.

Comment: @Serg - It is your question. Of course you disagree. But you show no research effort there. And the community has spoken.

Comment: @Serg Wether you agree or not, your question is of *poor* quality and needed to be closed. 5 users voted that it doesn't belong here. I would have voted that too.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment? I will not assume it is the OP, so would like whoever did downvote explain why this is a poor answer.

Comment: @Oded: The fact that it's my question doesn't affect my opinion. I wrote that question because I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere. Then I wrote the answer to share. 1000 people found it and probably were helped. If the community wants to delete it so be it, I don't take it personally; it's just a question. I only brought this up because I got the 1000 views badge notification. **Edit: I can't vote down here.**

Comment: *"1000 people found it"* Yep, absolutely. *"and probably were helped"* That's a bit of a stretch. But even if they were, the question is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Serg Your opinion is useless if you can't back it up.

Comment: *sniff* ... *sniff* ... Slowly smells like a reversal badge.

Answer (score 5):

1000 Views is not much **and** view count is not a protection against getting a question closed.

5 High reputation users with the power to speak for the community as of which questions are wanted here  closed a closed it as*Not a real question* .

> I think the sheer popularity of it should warrent it to be opened. Clearly people are finding it useful in answering this specific question.

No it should not. Improve the post and ask for it to be reopened after.

Answer (score 2):

The number of views does not correlate to whether a question is a "good" question (on topic, answerable, etc etc). For example, many questions with historical locks have hundreds of thousands of views - that doesn't mean they fit the current QA format of Stack Overflow, so they're closed.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the community has also determined the question is not only poor, but has now deleted it.

> This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Just because a question is popular does not mean it is a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Also, closed != deleted.

It was probably closed to prevent more answers and to demonstrate that those sort of questions ("I need... How to do it?") are not accepted here. Most likely the later.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, one of the red flags the downvoters might have seen is that you asked it and then tried to provide the definitive answer.  There are more than a few people who get put off by this type of activity.

I understand that this is something the community allows, and even encourages, just not everyone knows that.

> I think the sheer popularity of it should warrant it to be opened. Clearly people are finding it useful in answering this specific question.

Often people will just answer question for karma without an interest in whether its a good question or not.  Given how simple this one is, I'm guessing this is one such example.

Comment: People are encouraged to answer their own questions.

Comment: @Knights, I agree completely.  I was only trying to give a possible explanation to Serg.  I'm not sure why that would get downvoted:)

Comment: I don't think anyone would close a question because the author answered it; that just seems illogical.